# The second http request doesn’t work if I receive a 401 error

Tags: angular, rest, authentication

I tried to make a login in an Angular 4 application. I made the following request:

```
this.http.post(`https://api.knolge.com/auth/login`,
  'email=' + credential.email + '&password=' + credential.password,
  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
  })
  .catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  })
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err));
```

When receiving a 401 error from the server, the code from the catch block isn't executed, not is the code from subscribe, but if i try to make another login request without refreshing the page, the request isn't made. If the login is successful the first time, all is fine and it works.

How can I debug this and how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you clean up your question and the code a little? Is it always 401 status or do you get 201/200 codes as well?

Comment: When I try to login with bad credentials I receive 401 and when the credentials are correct I receive 200

Comment: Change HttpErrorResponse to any and see if the block is executed; if not there is some logic issue.Also,Usuallly request should return an observable which your component subscribe to and not all at once as we see here.

Comment: I changed error to any and the result is the same. The catch block wasn't executed. Don't see any logic issue.